# How to hide author information(byline) for authenticated users in Plone's view page?

Tags: plone, author

Plone 4.1.4
I can hide author information through Setup → Security  → uncheck "Allow anyone to view 'about' information". 
How could I hide author information(byline) for authenticated users?

Best Regards.

Hugo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the viewlet altogether. Add `/@@manage-viewlets` to the URL to access the viewlet management view, locate the `plone.belowcontenttitle.documentbyline` entry and click the "Hide" link.

Alternatively, you could include a `viewlets.xml` file in your policy product's GenericSetup profile with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<object>
  <hidden manager="plone.belowcontenttitle" skinname="[enter your site skin name here]">
    <viewlet name="plone.belowcontenttitle.documentbyline" />
  </hidden>
</object>
```

That'll mark the viewlet as hidden for a given skin name.

For folder views, you'll have to customize these individually; the `folder_summary_view.pt` template (the "Summary" display) for example, has a `<div class="documentByLine">` section you would have to adjust (it only displays authors for News Items).

Comment: Right, for folder views you have to customize the individual templates. Updated the answer.